# Regex not matching number as expected

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following string that I want to extract from:

```
/Monovolume/Honda+HR+V+1+6-11399031.htm
```

What I want to extract is the 8 digit number at the end which I tried with the following regex:

```
Monovolume\/.+(\d{7,})
```

It says 7 or more because there are cases where there are only 7 digits. The match, however, is only 7 digits and not 8 as in the above string. When I run the part in parentheses only I get the right result. What is causing this behaviour and how can I fix it?

P.S. I can't put the "-" in the regex, because its appearance is coincidental.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close. Your problem is that your `.+` will always consume one of the digits, as regex is by default "greedy".

I'm not sure about your requirements, but you could do a lazy match:

```
Monovolume\/.+?(\d{7,})
             /|\
              |
```

It will essentially repeat as few times as possible (when it reaches 7 or more digits).

**[See it live](http://rubular.com/r/8mFE5FUJlU)**

More info here: [Regex Lazy Quantification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_quantification)